# cybersource_rest_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.KeyGenerationApi is not a constructor

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource, cybersource-rest-client

When we update cybersource-rest-client version to ^0.0.40 to ^0.0.51 getting the below error

```
{
"errorCode": "FAILED",
"errorMessage": "TypeError: cybersource_rest_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.KeyGenerationApi is not a constructor"}
```

Code What we tried

```js
import { ApiClient, KeyGenerationApi, GeneratePublicKeyRequest } from 'cybersource-rest-client';
 const config = configuration(merchantDetails);
const apiClient = new ApiClient();
const instance = await new KeyGenerationApi(config, apiClient);
const request = await new GeneratePublicKeyRequest();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After version 0.0.41, KeyGenerationApi and GeneratePublicKeyRequest are removed and replaced by the below methods

```
import { ApiClient, MicroformIntegrationApi, GenerateCaptureContextRequest } from 'cybersource-rest-client';
```

---

```
const instance = await new KeyGenerationApi(config, apiClient);

to

const instance = new MicroformIntegrationApi(config, apiClient);
```

---

```
const request = await new GeneratePublicKeyRequest();

to

const request = await new GenerateCaptureContextRequest();
```

---

Key Generation

```
instance.generateCaptureContext(request, function (error, data) {
```

Comment: What's the source of this, Can you link that.